# Very high overfitting in image classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm a beginner in the development of CNNs and for a university assignment I've been tasked to create an image classificator for food items. The dataset I'm using is [Recipes5k](http://www.ub.edu/cvub/recipes5k/). It has 101 classes of foods:

I'm using Google Colab paired with the Tensorflow to achieve this and have been following [Tensorflow's image classification beginner tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification).

So far, everything has been clear and easy to understand but I've ran across a problem when it comes to training my model: The Validation Accuracy is outrageously low (10-11%) when compared to the training accuracy (90%+). I suspect this may be due to overfitting of the model. So far, I've tried image augmentation techniques and applying dropout to the model. This did not work as expected and only boosted the accuracy by about 5%. I have posted the code snippets necessary below:

**Data Augmentation layer:**

```
data_augmentation = keras.Sequential(
  [
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal", 
                                                 input_shape=(img_height, 
                                                              img_width,
                                                              3)),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.1),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomZoom(0.1),
  ]
)
```

**Model:**

```
model = Sequential([
  data_augmentation,
  layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.3),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
```

**Model Summary:**

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
sequential_1 (Sequential)    (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
rescaling_2 (Rescaling)      (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 224, 224, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 112, 112, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 112, 112, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 56, 56, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 56, 56, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 28, 28, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 28, 28, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 50176)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 128)               6422656   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 101)               13029     
=================================================================
Total params: 6,459,269
Trainable params: 6,459,269
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Results after training with 250 epochs**

```
Epoch 250/250
121/121 [==============================] - 3s 25ms/step - loss: 0.2564 - accuracy: 0.9270 - val_loss: 17.6184 - val_accuracy: 0.1202
```

[image: Results]

What other techniques can I use to improve the accuracy of my model?

**Update**: I followed Gerry P's suggestion and edited my last dense layer to work with softmax activation. The results of 1250 epochs of training presented a slower increase in training accuracy and around 5-6% more validation accuracy. This improved my model but it is still a very low accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

For your last dense layer change it to

```
layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
```

In `model.compile()` use

```
loss='categorical_crossentropy'
```

If your labels are one hot encoded. If they are integers then use

```
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I looked into the softmax function and applied it to my model to test with 100 epochs of training. The training accuracy increases much slower and there seems to be a better increase in validation accuracy, with the occasional "dip" whenever the model trains a different class. I'll do 1000 epochs and update you when it's done.

Comment: What do you mean "when the model trains a different class"? Are you training on all samples from one class and then move to the next class? That should definitely be randomized.

Comment: Sorry, it is in fact randomized. What I meant is, because the validation accuracy gets lower every once in a while, I can only assume that epoch of training contains more samples of a class that hasn't been trained yet / enough, resulting in less accuracy. It eventually goes back up after a short while